# On the wallpaper is a horse - is the sentence correct?

Tags: prepositions, difference, word-order

> On the wallpaper there is a horse.

Is the sentence correct or must I change it somehow?

In other words:

Is there any difference between these sentences?

1. There is a picture of a horse on the wallpaper.
2. On the wallpaper there is a picture of a horse.

My question relates to a phone screen.

Does the sentence beginning with "On" sound artificial to you or is it perfectly correct?

Could I write?:

> On the phone screen there is a wallpaper of a horse.
>
> On the phone screen there is a horse wallpaper.

or

> On the phone screen is a wallpaper of a horse.
>
> On the phone screen is a horse wallpaper.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you talking about the pattern on the wallpaper, or did a horse walk into your house whilst you were decorating? More background information, **please**!

Comment: I mean there is a picture of a horse on the wallpaper.

Comment: It's *grammatically* correct, if that's what you mean.  Whether it's clear and understandable is another issue.  Out of context, it's hard to understand.  Usually, wallpaper contains repeating patterns, not just one picture, so I would expect to see "There were horse*s* on the wallpaper."

Comment: How about this sentence?:
On the wallpaper there is a picture of a horse.

Comment: That's _much_ better!

Comment: Are you talking about a [wallpaper with an image of a  horse](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wallpaper+horse&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiPvMK38dXOAhURsBQKHWQeCcYQ_AUIBigB), the ones you can download from the Internet? Or are you talking about [horse wallpaper](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5e/4f/8d/5e4f8d70184afb7f9831cdcda3e6cdad.jpg)?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have been more precise. I am talking about a wallpaper with an image of a horse on the phone screen.

Comment: @masterkomp You need to put that explanation in the body of your question.

Comment: I think the comments speak for themselves. The sentence examples are unclear, and confusing.

Comment: How about "there is a picture of a horse on the phone screen."

Comment: Since you're talking about the background image on a phone or computer screen, you can also say "The wallpaper _is_ a picture of a horse."

Comment: On the phone screen there is a wallpaper of a horse. How about this?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I disagree. There'd be no problem for a native speaker there at all.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe best to delete your last addition to your question. It's already very complicated and you're going to get lot's of bad answers and irrelevant corrections if you leave that bit in ... :-)

Comment: @masterkomp: RE: _I'm sorry. I should have been more precise._ That's the best thing you've said all day! :-) I find these questions you've been asking quite interesting. However, I hope you've learned a lesson: you can't ask, "Can I say X to describe Y?" unless you provide a **very** clear picture or description of **exactly** what Y is! In the future, please take a little extra time to ask a question that won't require so many clarifications and edits.

Comment: I know. I'd be more careful next time ;) Sorry. Now I am myself confused :D

Comment: Please delete your last four examples - they just complicate the question instead of making it clear. It ws a good question before. You just had really poor answers and comments.

Comment: @Araucaria and I disagree, until the OP clarified, please see edit history, nobody really understood what he was on about. Please also see  JavaLatte's first comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think if you wandered into a situation and heard "and on the wallpaper was a horse" you'd be unlikely to understand that there was a physyical horse on a roll of wallpaper. But either way, that's not very helpful to point out this unlikely ambiguity. It's the same as "on the TV that night there was a big debate". That's not grammar, it's just pragmatics - and the common sense of the listener.

Comment: @Araucaria please see my first comment, and the links,  I was the first to guess the OP might be referring to a screensaver. My comment, if you don't mind, *was* very helpful.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It makes no difference at all if it was physical wallpaper or a screensaver wallpaper. Absolutely none.

Comment: @Araucaria There's no difference in meaning? There's no difference between an image you download on your phone, and a roll of wallpaper. That's news to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There's a difference in meaning old bean, but no, there's no difference to the answer to the question. Reason is that the question asks whether it is ok to prepose a Locative Complement of the verb *BE*. In the OP's example the displaced Subject is indefinite and discourse-new, the Complement is known and discourse-old. Therefore OP's formulation is entirely correct. What *wallpaper* means is irrelevant to the grammar, you see.

Comment: Araucaria's analysis is precise and perfectly reasoned, as expected. Mari-LouA and J.R. also raise important points. However, the ambiguity unintentionally introduced by the original question seems to me also interesting and important—and so is _fun._

Answer (score 4):

A sentence which begins with a preposition, like yours, is *perfectly correct,* and it would be inaccurate to characterize it as sounding *artificial.* Your sentence as written is not *wrong,* and one reasonable interpretation of your sentence is exactly what you intended to say. It is not the way most native English speakers would express this particular thought, but in literature and formal writing you will find many beautifully-composed sentences which begin with **On.** To cite just a few:

> [On my volcano grows the grass](http://www.bartleby.com/113/5127.html),—
>   A meditative spot,
>   An area for a bird to choose
>   Would be the general thought.

---

> [On the Mountains of the Prairie,](http://www.hwlongfellow.org/poems_poem.php?pid=63)
>   On the great Red Pipe-stone Quarry,
>   Gitche Manito, the mighty,
>   He the Master of Life, descending,
>   On the red crags of the quarry
>   Stood erect, and called the nations,
>   Called the tribes of men together.

---

> [On the beach at night alone](http://www.bartleby.com/142/218.html),
>   As the old mother sways her to and fro, singing her husky song,
>   As I watch the bright stars shining—I think a thought of the clef of the universes, and of the future.

These examples illustrate the way in which a sentence beginning with **On** may be perceived, and that may be part of the reason why your first sentence strikes some native English speakers as mildly humorous: the juxtaposition of a form which brings to mind poetic expression with such prosaic things as a horse and wallpaper seems incongruous, especially before we learn that the wallpaper here is a background image on an electronic screen.

Below is one example of the image your sentence might conjure in the mind of the reader:
[image: Horsepaper]

Because the preposition **on** can mean so many things in English, your sentence lends itself to an interpretation which brings to mind a humorous image. It is sometimes important to express a thought carefully in order to avoid unintentional [Ambiguity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzm0x.png); as some of the commentary to your question indicates, this is a fertile source of humor.

There are many ways in which your sentence might be interpreted. If you wish to describe a background image (sometimes referred to as *wallpaper*) for use on a computer or handheld device, you might say:

> - The background image pictures a horse.
> - The wallpaper* image shows a horse.
> - On the computer wallpaper is a picture of a horse.
> - There is a picture of a horse on the wallpaper*.

* This could denote any kind of wallpaper, even the kind we put on walls.

Comment: I appreciate you including the image of the horse on the wallpaper; that's an important point to make about inherent ambiguities in English. However, I strongly disagreed with the way you worded your original assertion: _Your sentence is correct only if this is what you wish to describe_. Horsefeathers! The preposition _on_ has multiple meanings, and there is **nothing** wrong with saying, "There are horses on [this wallpaper](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e3/7e/a9/e37ea95f5cc3242687c217cf05764938.jpg)." It's not any different than asking, "Whose face is on this coin?"

Comment: /me searches for images of pinnine equines...

Comment: @J.R. And now? (I'm reminded here of _Put the book in the bag on the table._)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Oh, that's a good edit. (I'd remove my downvote if I had cast one, but I figured you'd fix this in pretty short order, so I didn't bother.)

Comment: Apparently I still have a downvote because I neglected to shadow the horse!

Comment: On the computer wallpaper is a picture of a horse.
vs On the computer wallpaper there is a picture of a horse.
Is there any difference?

Comment: @masterkomp No diiference at all!

Comment: @Araucaria - I have to disagree with _an ambiguity that would never arise in a conversation._ Without any context, if someone said to me _"On the wallpaper there is a horse,"_ I would be puzzled, and that's exactly what I was when I first saw the question. Isn't it revelatory that several other readers were puzzled, too? I think ambiguity is an important subject for learners to be cognizant of, especially when it leads to unintentionally humorous statements. Let's allow for a little serendipity, shall we? You're right about not addressing the question, though, and I've corrected that.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What would be confusing you there would be the definite article in *the wallpaper*.There is no more ambiguity because of *on* there than there is in *there is a meeting on the agenda*, etc, etc.

Comment: That keeps the funness and less misleading. However! In the interests of excellence! In actual fact, Subject-Complement inversion is a very common everyday kind of construction. It happens very often when we have an indefinite Subject and a Locative Complement. Consider *And on the corner is a cafe* or *In the corner you'll find an old box full of tennis balls.* Without a previous sentence it will tend to sound very literary, but when found in context, it's quite natural. In OP's context, what would make it natural is a previous sentence mentioning the wallpaper. +1 for pictures + fun.

Comment: @Araucaria There are demurrers, but I wouldn't characterize the present writer as "confused." And of course; it's trivial to say that _On wallpaper there is a horse_ is just an absurdity. If I were told that _On wallpaper there is a horse,_ I would but nod and assent to the truth of it. Ambiguity in the OP's question arises just as I explain in my answer: the elegant, poetic "On the.." followed by a horse and wallpaper. Really, I laughed _out loud_ when I read it. If it does _not_ strike you as funny, I'm out of my depth. I could no more explain it than I could explain why swimming is fun.

Answer (score 1):

This construction is grammatically correct and will be readily understood, although it's perhaps a bit unusual.  It's more associated with old-fashioned or poetic writing, e.g. Tolkein's famous opening line

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.

but it's not strange enough that anyone would think it was out of place.  It certainly does *not* mean that there's an actual horse standing on the wallpaper.

Comment: +1 ***However***, I do not agree it's odd. It is only odd without the previous sentence.

Comment: Although it _could_ mean there was a horse standing on a roll of wallpaper (very unlikely, but possible). I'm reminded of Groucho Marx's famous quip: _The other day I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know._

Comment: @J.R. Yep +1 .[but only as a temporary comment] (It's funny, but not helpful given the comments and answers around here ...)

Comment: @J.R. ...or Forster's immortal _The American women shoot the hippopotamus with eyebrows made of platinum._ When prepositions wander, confusion ensues.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - If it weren't for prepositions, verb tenses, and words like _could_ and _would_, we probably wouldn't need to have an ELL. :-)

Comment: The original sentence, before Aracaria edited/corrected it, was: *on the wallpaper is a horse*. The sentence was ambiguous. Now its meaning  is clearer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They are both equally ambiguous/not ambiguous depending on the context. In almost any context they are not ambiguous at all. But one thing is for certain: it makes no difference whether it's an existential construction or not. The comments and answers on this post are seriously unhelpful for future users. The question is whether we can prepose the PP here.

Comment: @Araucaria the title and the first quote are different. The OP is asking about eight sentences, no one told him to do that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, the original question would seem to be - on a straight-forward reading - whether you can invert the PP complement with the Subject. It does not seem to be asking whether someone might think there is a horse physically standing on some wallpaper. Why someone should think that escapes me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yep, the asking loads of extra extraneous questions isn't good.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct although I find the second more natural. I would be more likely to use the first one as part of a fuller description of the phone as in "My phone is a black iPhone6. On the wallpaper is a picture of a horse." Having said that I would probably say, in this context, "The wallpaper is a picture of a horse." since most phone wallpapers are single images. Hope this helps.